# AWS Ruby SDK CORE: Upload files to S3

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to upload a file (any file, could be a .txt, .mp4, .mp3, .zip, .tar ...etc) to AWS S3 using [AWS-SDK-CORE ruby SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/frames.html)

Here is my code:

```
require 'aws-sdk-core'
Aws.config = {
  :access_key_id => MY_ACCESS_KEY
  :secret_access_key => MY_SECRET_KEY,
  :region => 'us-west-2'
}

s3 = Aws::S3.new
resp = s3.put_object(
  :bucket => "mybucket",
  :key => "myfolder/upload_me.sql",
  :body => "./upload_me.sql"
)
```

Now, Above code runs and creates a key `myfolder/upload_me.sql` which has only one line written and that is `./upload_me.sql` which is wrong. The file `upload_me.sql` has several lines.

Expected behaviour is to upload the file `upload_me.sql` on S3 as `mybucket/myfolder/upload_me.sql`. But instead it just writes one line to `mybucket/myfolder/upload_me.sql` and that is `./upload_me.sql`

Now, If I omit the `:body` part as below:

```
s3 = Aws::S3.new
resp = s3.put_object(
  :bucket => "mybucket",
  :key => "myfolder/upload_me.sql",
)
```

Then it just creates and empty key called `mybucket/myfolder/upload_me.sql` which is not even downloadable (well, even if it gets downloaded, it is useless)

Could you point me where I am going wrong?

Here is ruby-SDK-core documentation for `put_object` Method: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/S3/V20060301.html#put_object-instance_method

**UPDATE:**
If I try to upload the same file using AWS-CLI, it gets uploaded fine. Here is the command:

```
aws s3api put-object --bucket mybucket --key myfolder/upload_me.sql --body ./upload_me.sql
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So, After spending a frustrating sunday afternoon on htis issue, I finally cracked it. What I really needed is **`:body => IO.read("./upload_me.sql")`**

So my code looks like below:

```
s3 = Aws::S3.new
resp = s3.put_object(
  :bucket => "mybucket",
  :key => "myfolder/upload_me.sql",
  :body => IO.read("./upload_me.sql")
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The body variable is the contents that will be written to S3. So if you send a file to S3 you need to manually load by using File.read("upload_me.sql") something similar.

```
s3 = Aws::S3.new
resp = s3.put_object(
  :bucket => "mybucket",
  :key => "myfolder/upload_me.sql",
  :body => File.read("./upload_me.sql")
)
```

According to the documentation another way to do this is to use write on the bucket.

```
s3 = AWS::S3.new
key = File.basename(file_name)
s3.buckets["mybucket"].objects[key].write(:file => "upload_me.sql")
```

Comment: The `another way to do this` is for the [older AWS SDK for ruby](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjSingleOpRuby.html). It needs `require 'aws-sdk'`. I am using newer ruby AWS-SDK-CORE which needs `require 'aws-sdk-core`'. Also, the older SDK defines object as `AWS::S3.new` whereas the newer sdk defines object as `Aws::S3.new`. And the 1st solution of using `File.read` may not work for non-text files. Thanks for your time.

Comment: +1. Hey @Pafjo, You response got my head spinning in right direction. I have posted the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be

```
AWS.config(
    :access_key_id => 'MY_ACCESS_KEY',
    :secret_access_key => 'MY_SECRET_KEY',
)

#Set the filename
file_name = 'filename.txt'

#Set the bucket name
s3_bucket_name = 'my bucket name'

#If file has to go in some specific folder
bucket_directory = 'key or folder'

begin
  s3 = AWS::S3.new

  #Check if directory name has provided and Make an object in your bucket for your upload
  if bucket_directory == ''
    bucket_obj = s3.buckets[s3_bucket_name].objects[bucket_directory]
  else
    bucket_obj = s3.buckets[s3_bucket_name].objects["#{bucket_directory}/#{file_name}"]
  end

  # Upload the file
  bucket_obj.write(:file => file_name)
  puts "File was successfully uploaded : #{bucket_obj}"
rescue Exception => e
  puts "There was an error in uploading file: #{e}"
end
```

[Working Example](https://github.com/ahmadhasankhan/ruby-scripts/blob/master/s3_upload.rb)

[Reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/S3/S3Object.html)

Answer (score 0):

Probably the file wasn't found as the path is relative.
This is a strange behavior, where the interface try to make too many decisions.

I can assure you this works (v3):

```rb
client = Aws::S3::Client.new(...)
client.put_object(
  body: './existing_file.txt',
  bucket: 'kick-it',
  key: 'test1.txt'
) # kick-it:/test1.txt contains the same as the contents of existing_file.txt

client.put_object(
  body: './non_existing_file.txt',
  bucket: 'kick-it',
  key: 'test2.txt'
) # kick-it:/test2.txt contains just the string './non_existing_file.txt'
```

Using body for both cases is a bad decision, if you ask me.