# How to upload a transcoded file to s3 and create a link to download it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, ffmpeg

I want to download a video after my module "creates" it by combining a picture and audio file. The output goes to my tmp folder. This works, but I don't know how to access it.

My method is to create another Paperclip attachment called "converted" and the module responsible for transcoding should also be responsible for uploading the converted video to a bucket, where I can then access it via `@upload.converted.url`.

I have no idea how to go about this, and my eyes hurt from searching. If you have a better way for me to be able to download the transcoded video without this option, I will be open to it.

```rb
# videocreatingproccessor.rb

require 'streamio-ffmpeg'
require 'fileutils'

module VideoCreatingProcessor
  def self.convert_to_video (path_to_audio_file, path_to_image_file)
    movie = FFMPEG::Movie.new(path_to_audio_file)
    options = {
      video_codec: "libx264",
      frame_rate: 60,
      resolution: "960x720",
      x264_vprofile: "high",
      x264_preset: "slow",
      pixel_format: "720p",
      audio_codec: "libfaac",
      audio_bitrate: 32,
      audio_sample_rate: 44100,
      audio_channels: 2,
      threads: 2,
    }

    woptions = { watermark: path_to_image_file, resolution: "960x720", watermark_filter: { padding_x: 10, padding_y: 10 } }

    movie.transcode("tmp/output.mp4",woptions ,options )
  end
end
```

```rb
# uploads_controller.rb

class UploadsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_upload, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @uploads = Upload.all
  end

  def paudioaddress
    "https:" + @upload.audio.url
  end

  def pimageaddress
    "https:" + @upload.image.url
  end

   def show
    require "video_creating_processor"
    newvideo = VideoCreatingProcessor.convert_to_video(paudioaddress, pimageaddress)
   end

   # ....
end
```

Comment: I'd recommend that you get in the habit of correctly indenting your code. It will make your life much easier, plus it's the Ruby-way. Your source code isn't syntactically correct, which indenting would tell you right away.

Comment: In addition to what @theTinMan said about formatting, please format your code so the reader doesn't have to scroll.

Comment: programmatically uploading to S3 is definitely doable but you should look at existing tutorials first. You'll also need to add a public-ready policy to your S3 bucket. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23040651/aws-ruby-sdk-core-upload-files-to-s3 for an example of how to upload files. Also see [here](https://gist.github.com/MaxPleaner/d42ba0e30802946e2d33428741f5af6a) for some bucket-creation helpers.